# --experiments Option Behavior with use_beam_bq_sink

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I had a question about option parsing for Apache Beam in Google Cloud deployment. Currently my project uses the following option when deploying:  `--experiments use_beam_bq_sink`.

However, currently we need to enable runner_v2 as well, which uses the option `--experiments=use_runner_v2`, which follows a different format. How would I go about enabling both options?

Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried enabling both options with separate --experiments flags, setting both values separated by spaces and then again separated by commas, which resulted in "unparseable" warning on execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue, you can use `experiments` and `--additional-experiments` arguments, example :

```bash
python -m folder.main
 --experiments=use_runner_v2 \
 --additional-experiments=use_beam_bq_sink \
 ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Just to follow-up: is --additional-experiments a more recent addition to the Beam SDK? We're currently using an older SDK and the option is registered as unparseable.

Comment: Yes it’s recent, which version are you using ? For older versions you can try to repeat the experiments options several times

Comment: It's v2.28.0; we're migrating to a newer version but in the meantime enabling runner_v2 was important. I'll try it and come back with the outcome!

Comment: It appears that using two --experiments options did the trick but runner_v2 had some compatibility issues unrelated to options. I'll have to upgrade the SDK necessarily but the answer given was correct. Thanks again!